# What is covering conditions?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I heard of covering relations in order theory but never heard of covering conditions. I am a new teacher assigned to teach Boolean algebra and i got the syllabus containing a topic 'covering conditions'. Now i am confused whether covering conditions is same as covering relation or, is different from covering relation or the syllabus is misprinted.

Comment: There's the [Upper covering condition](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oTQDCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=upper+covering+condition&source=bl&ots=9yIIQKqEuq&sig=Uxm3sq0T6Lc4t6MuPIxdKB3uxtw&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieu9qM_-TZAhUEPxQKHUP9DMIQ6AEIUjAG#v=onepage&q=upper%20covering%20condition&f=false) and its dual, the lower covering condition for lattices. But these are always satisfied in distributive lattices, and thus, in Boolean algebras, so it must not be that...

Comment: @amrsa you are right. Thank you